# PopupWindow TouchInterceptor not working

Tags: android, popupwindow, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to test the PopupWindow class. I've created this method to show the popup:

```
    public void showPopup(){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
            popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popup.setTouchable(true);
            popup.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("POPUP", event.toString());
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                        popup.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 200);
}
```

The popup is showing correctly,by the way it seems that the Touch Interceptor don't work at all: I don't get any log information and of course the popup is not dismissing if pressing outside of it.

Is there some further property I have to set in the popup or in the Activity which host it?

Comment: I had this same problem, let me remember how I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 pw.setBackgroundDrawable (new BitmapDrawable());
 pw.setFocusable(false);
 pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

use this code hope this is helpful

Comment: Hi I have been working on a piece of code which has list inside a popup window. So I want it to be focusable. How do I handle any outside touch events to dismiss this popup window. In my next comment I will paste my approach

Comment: popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     popupWindow.dismiss();
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
      Log.e(TAG, "some event happened outside window: action outside");
      
      return true;
     }
     Log.e(TAG, "some event happened outside window");
     
     return false;
    }
   });

Comment: you just remove your piece of code and add my above code , hope it will work

Comment: I tried your code and posted my problem after it. Your code sets popupwindow focusable state to false, which closes the popupwindow when touched outside or inside. However, in my scenario, there are items which I want to be selected(toggled) and hence for that I require focus. How would I solve this problem?

Comment: This worked for me in the case to hide PW when click out size. This like a miracle!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do some action, when it's clicked outside window and both `setFocusable()` + `setOutsideTouchable()` you need true, you might consider using `setOnDismissListener`. It's method `onDismiss` is called, as expected, when dialog dialog is dismissed:

```
  PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mRootView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
  mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
  mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
  mPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDismiss() {
        // some action ....
      }
  });
```

Comment: I tried with your solution it works good. However once this function executes and if I click any button the app gets crash stating the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` Tried finding out to resolve but didn't achieved. Any Suggestions on it?

Comment: This happens when you try to add a view to the view hierarchy multiple times. You should look for `addView()` or `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.xyz, parentView, true)`.