# android setTouchInterceptor not working

Tags: android

Can anyone help me why setTouchInterceptor not working i tried all possible solutions available even the error log is also not printing.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.away_dropdown, null, true);
            final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(rowView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popUp.showAsDropDown(awayFilter, 0, 0);
            popUp.setContentView(rowView);
            popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true); 
            popUp.setTouchable(true);
            popUp.setFocusable(true);
            popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popUp.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     Log.e("woofyz", "outsideClick");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                      popUp.dismiss(); 
                      return true;
                    }
                  return false; 
                } 
            });`

> enter code here

`
```

Comment: yes but i added the solution avaialbe there but it is still not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570172/popupwindow-touchinterceptor-not-working?lq=1 related

Comment: my log is not displaying so basically it is not going inside onTouch